# How to prevent onChange event from firing if a value is assigned dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let item of collectionValues">   
 <ion-checkbox slot="end" (ionChange)="onCheckBoxChange(item, $event)" 
        [(ngModel)]="item.value">
        </ion-checkbox>
 </ng-container>
```

This is ok but the problem is that if a value is assigned to `item.value` from the code in .ts i.e. then the `onCheckBoxChange()` is called which I don't want to. I have tried using the `(click)` event but that is not what I want.
how do I prevent it from going to `onCheckBoxChange` event if a value is assigned. It should only go to the event if checked from UI.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Angular Documentation you can use ngModelChange for your scenario

> Event emitter for producing the ngModelChange event after the view
> model updates.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of collectionValues">   
 <ion-checkbox slot="end" (ngModelChange)="onCheckBoxChange(item, $event)" 
        [(ngModel)]="item.value">
        </ion-checkbox>
 </ng-container>
```

Comment: ah ok, let me try

Comment: hi, there'sa problem with this. Now, when I change the selection from UI it doesn't hit the event :(

Comment: any idea on how to get done with this? i tried it but no hit.

Comment: It will if you change it from ui

Comment: i tried but not.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz